# Copy contents of current worksheet to vba created worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm tearing my hair out trying to do what should be a really simple adjustment to a macro.

copy and paste doesn't seem to work.  I get a property not supported error.

All I am trying to do is copy all cell contents from the original activesheet in the originating workbook (which will be sName) and paste it to the new workbook sheet(rvname)

Here is my current code: (I need it to work in excel 2003 and 2007)

```
Sub create_format_wb()
    'This macro will create a new workbook
    'Containing sheet1,(job plan) Original, (job plan) Revised, and 1 sheet for each task entered in the inputbox.


Dim Newbook As Workbook
Dim i As Integer
Dim sName As String
Dim umName As String
Dim rvName As String
Dim tBox As Integer
Dim jobplannumber As String
Dim oldwb As String


line1:
tBox = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Enter Number of Tasks", Type:=1)
If tBox < 1 Then
MsgBox "Must be at least 1"
GoTo line1
Else

sName = ActiveSheet.Name
umName = (sName & " Original")
rvName = (sName & " Revised")
jobplannumber = sName




Set Newbook = Workbooks.Add
    With Newbook
        .Title = sName
        .SaveAs Filename:=(sName & " .xls")
        .Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1
        .Sheets.Add(, After:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = umName
        Worksheets(umName).Range("A1").Select
        With Worksheets(umName).QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
            "ODBC;DSN=MX7PROD;Description=MX7PROD;APP=Microsoft Office 2003;WSID=USOXP-93BPBP1;DATABASE=MX7PROD;Trusted_Connection=Yes" _
            , Destination:=Range("A1"))
            .CommandText = Array( _
            "SELECT jobplan_print.taskid, jobplan_print.description, jobplan_print.critical" & Chr(13) _
            & "" & Chr(10) & "FROM MX7PROD.dbo.jobplan_print jobplan_print" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) _
            & "WHERE (jobplan_print.jpnum= '" & jobplannumber & "' )")
            .Name = "Query from MX7PROD"
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .BackgroundQuery = True
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .PreserveColumnInfo = True
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With
            .Worksheets(umName).UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
            .Sheets.Add(, After:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = rvName
            For i = 1 To tBox
                .Sheets.Add(, After:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = ("Task " & i)
            Next i
    End With


    Worksheets(rvName).UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
End If
End Sub
```

Can somone walk me through how to go about this?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Step 1: Either wrap your workbook-line in an error catcher or create a naming function that checks for existing workbook names in that directory. Step 2: Can you add a bit more of information? Perhaps an example of the data? Elaborate how you are trying to 'copy' the data. It looks like you're trying to query info into the document but you say you're trying to 'copy/paste' it? I may be mis-reading something here.

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer.

Comment: The above macro works just fine.  It creates a new workbook, queries our internal database and populates new workbook sheet umName with the data.  What I need to do is copy the entire contents of the originating workbook current sheet to the newly created sheet rvName.

Comment: If the name already exists in the directory it will either crash or at best change the name which will break any code run thereafter, but that's up to you. It was just some (albeit unsolicited) advice. Regarding the problem, I apologize, but I was actually typing up a solution for you but something came up at work. If things slow down again I'll post my answer including a revised copy of your subroutine.

Comment: hmm...  In my tests with xl 2003 all it did was tell me that the file already existed, and do I want to replace it.  Is this something that will break in other versions?

Comment: Actually THAT should work fine, except you are deleting whatever it is replacing. If you choose "Save but keep both copies" or something, it will change the name of the workbook and it is likely that VBA is not equipped to handle that lol.

Comment: excellent point.  Since this macro will only ever be run once per worksheet from a single computer I should see if I can force-replace the file if it is run more than once (that is the desired result).  Do you know off hand if there is a built in property for this?

Comment: Yes you can use Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
Sub Copy()
    Workbooks("Book1").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.Copy
    Workbooks("Book2").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Select
    Workbooks("Book2").Worksheets("Sheet1").Paste
End Sub
```

FYI, if you record macros in Excel while doing the operations you'd like to code, you can often get what you're looking for with minimal modifications to the automatically-generated macro code.

Comment: Thank you all. Still trying to get the hang of this message box format.

Comment: From your comment in Joe Mahley's answer, it looks like you eventually got it to work based on my solution, right?  Could you please give me credit by accepting this as the answer?

Comment: Yes.  I was originally trying to do the same thing using the workbook.add properties, but I guess .paste is not a valid property.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

To copy the contents of a worksheet to another *existing* worksheet:

```
wsDest.UsedRange.Clear 'Clear the contents of the destination sheet
wsSource.UsedRange.Copy Destination:=wsDest.Range("A1")
```

Where `wsSource` and `wsDest` are the source and destination worksheets respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider copying the worksheet as a whole? Here's a basic example, you'll have to customize your workbook organization and naming requirements.

```
Sub CopyWkst()
    Dim wksCopyMe As Worksheet

    Set wksCopyMe = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    wksCopyMe.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Worksheets.Count)
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name = "I'm New!"

End Sub
```